# Would creating a recoverable error interface be more effecient than handling recovery in 'catch'

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

**Note**  This question was closed as being opinion based, so I re-asked with a more factual approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013014/would-creating-a-recoverable-error-interface-be-more-effecient-than-handling-rec)

So, as the title says, I'm unsure if I should try to implement recoverable error classes or just stick with trying to recover in a `catch` block.

Some psuedo-code to demonstrate:

```
// more or less what I have now
postToServer(data) {
    try {
        socket.write(data)
    }
    //Interrupted being a custom exception
    catch(Interrupted ex) {
        //happened twice is a common static method on all custom exceptions that returns a boolean indicating if the last thrown error is the same as this one
        if(Interrupted.happenedTwice(ex)) throw ex;
        else postToServer(data);
    } 
    //another custom exception indicating that the network is unreachable
    catch(NetworkDrop ex) {
        if(!NetworkDrop.happenedTwice(ex) && !reconnectToServer()) throw ex;
        else postToServer(data);
    }
}
//What I would like to implement
interface Recoverable {
    public void recover(Runnable) throws Exception;
}
class NetworkDrop extends Exception implements Recoverable {
    ...
    public void recover(Runnable resume) {
        if(!NetworkDrop.happenedTwice(this) && reconnectToServer()) resume.run();
        else throw this;
    } 
}
class Interrupted extends Exception implements Recoverable {
    ...
    public void recover(Runnable resume) {
        if(!Interrupted.happenedTwice(this)) resume.run();
        else throw this;
    }     
}
postToServer(data) throws Exception {
    try {
        socket.write(data)
    }
    catch(Recoverable ex) {
        ex.recover(() -> postToServer(data));
    }
}
```

As the example, I'd like to have all the recovery code in the exception (reduces duplicate code, as now say 5 different methods can just call `recover` instead of running the same recovery code).  This would allow me to catch exceptions that can be recovered, but still throw unrecoverable ones, or throw if recovery can't be done.

I see an issue with this though:

How would I recover inside a method that is expected to return data, when the intermediate `Runnable` called from recovery doesn't return data?
Say hypothetically I'm reading from the server instead of writing, and get a recoverable exception (such as NetworkDrop) and successfully recover. Since execution is resumed through the Runnable on the recover method, and Runnable doesn't return anything, so how would the function that called the read get the data out of the Runnable?

So, would this system be more efficient that multiple `catch`'s? Or is the readability and simplicity I get from only catching recoverable exceptions a double edged sword?

And if the tradeoff favors Recoverable classes, how would I address the issue of getting a return value from a recovered exception?

Comment: It sounds overcomplicated and generally worse than try-catch. WRT to your example "*I can call recover with a Runnable that retries the last operation, which will check file access, make the parent directories*" then my question would be - if you think it's possible that the permissions were wrong, or directories didn't exist, why didn't you make sure they were **before** trying to access the file? Exceptions are for exceptional situations. "didn't bother to check a file exists before accessing it" is not exceptional.

Comment: @Michael I understand where your coming from. That was probably a bad example, but it was easy to come up with ;) I had thought of this mostly being useful for thread tasks in embedded situations, so I'll use that as an example, like sending a SPI device data, the device is in a bad state, so recover by forcing the device to restart, and call the runnable when the device has restarted

Comment: By all means, if this is a bad idea, make an answer saying so and why it is so others can reference it, and I'll accept it

Comment: I specifically looked at a download chain in an program, that downloads multiple files, and got an eyesore looking all all of the nested try/catch blocks and decided I would prefer to tuck all that away into a class I never have to look at. I figured make an interface, have every custom exception that can be possibly be recovered, like interruptions or timeouts implement the recover function, so my code can be cleaner by just catching the exception top level, and just calling recover (if the exception is recoverable) with the task that threw

Comment: So instead of looking at `catch (interrupted) { /*yada yada check and recover*/ submitTask(task);}` I can just look at `catch(recoverable) {recoverable.recover(task);}`

Comment: I think we need to see the actual code to make any informed judgement. I can see what you are getting at, and my intuition is that it will not be a good approach, but to precisely explain why I would need to demonstrate with some concrete examples.

Comment: Only you can answer this opinion-based question about what your own time is worth.

Comment: If you search ideas and inspiration for better error handling, my personal advice would be to read about frameworks modeling your app as a pipeline/operation graph (actor model, reactive streams) or at functional programing. For example, you can read [error handling section in Spring reactor doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.0/reference/index.html#error.handling) (retry operators are especially close to your initial question I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are meant to communicate failure up the call stack. Throwing an exception especially supports the aspect that, after a failure in some nested call, the caller typically doesn't want to continue, but signal its failure further up the stack.

So, after receiving an exception, your caller skips the rest of its method body, and signals failure to its caller, and this happens up all the call stack until you hit a place with an appropriate `catch` block.

### Flaws

Your `Recoverable` exceptions will break that system. If I understand correctly, recovery is a two-fold process: the exception contains the code how to e.g. re-establish a connection, and the Runnable is provided by the catch block, with the responsibility to repair the code lines skipped because of the exception.

But as the code skipped will come from multiple nested call layers, I don't think you can reliably provide valid recovery code.

Of course this can be made easier if you are ready to surround each and every line of business code with try/catch, on each and every software layer, but this contradicts the spirit of exception handling.

To establish your concept, you anyway need to identify all the places where a recoverable failure might happen - you have to throw `Recoverable` exceptions, typically wrapping some original one. And this is the key to a different approach.

### Suggestion

I suggest to use a different approach:

In all the places where you'd throw recoverable exceptions, you know that you can recover from the failure. So, I'd implement that knowledge in that place, and instead of having the method fail, immediately apply the recovery strategy, so you can return successfully.

If you're worried about wasting too many attempts if recovery fails, have a look at the "circuit breaker" pattern.

Comment: Thank you for a very informative post! This is a lot more informative and helpful than others just questing why you want to and saying don't because they don't understand.

Comment: My impression is that exceptions are the most ill-understood software feature today. Even reputed tutorials typically just cover the mechanics and not the soul of exceptions. So I try to share my understanding, hoping that it turns out to be useful.

Comment: It is much appreciated good sir. I re-asked my question more factually here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013014/would-creating-a-recoverable-error-interface-be-more-effecient-than-handling-rec Would you be able to check it out and provide feedback on that as well? Just for the second opinion haha